# Core Data add attributes to entries programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I just got started with core data. I have bunch of entities with about 40-50 attributes. Given that I have an array of strings which represent the name of the attributes (the type of these attributes are all string), is there a way I can programmatically set the attributes from the array? or do I have to manually copy paste these attributes into the Xcode IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While fiddling with the sqlite data store will not help you, there is a file that describes the data model inside your project folder. This file is in **xml format** so you could iterate through your array and generate the necessary entries into this file. You could then overwrite the default file and reopen your project in Xcode. If you are lucky all your entities and attributes will be there.

To get you started let me point you to the file. If you just start a new project with the default core data model included, it should be located at

```
<project directory>/<project name>/project_name.xcdatamodeld/project_name.xcdatamodel
```

The default looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<model name="Test1.xcdatamodel" userDefinedModelVersionIdentifier="" type="com.apple.IDECoreDataModeler.DataModel" documentVersion="1.0" lastSavedToolsVersion="1" systemVersion="11A491" minimumToolsVersion="Automatic" macOSVersion="Automatic" iOSVersion="Automatic">
    <entity name="Event">
        <attribute name="timeStamp" optional="YES" attributeType="Date"/>
    </entity>
    <elements>
        <element name="Event" positionX="261" positionY="189" width="128" height="60"/>
    </elements>
</model>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not at all supported by Apple. Please refrain from using this.

Comment: Just to re-iterate Daniel's comment. Please don't do this. Apple provide perfectly usable APIs for modifying a managed object model at runtime (see the NSManagedObjectModel API docs for more). Don't mess around with the xcdatamodel file - it's purpose is to support the Xcode model editor and is *not* documented or supported.

Answer (score 10):

You can create your model programatically. The Xcode IDE is just what's easiest for most people.

Create your model with

```
NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Then create your entities with

```
NSMutableArray *entities = [NSMutableArray array];
NSEntityDescription *event = [[[NSEntityDescription alloc] init] autorelease];
[entities addObject:event];
[event setName:@"Event"];
[event setProperties:eventProperties];
...
```

Then add the entities to the model:

```
[mom setEntities:entities];
```

Note that you can't change the model once you're using it with a store / context.

Once you've created your model, you can save it using NSCoding.

This is also shown in the [Core Data Utility Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataUtilityTutorial/Articles/00_introduction.html).

Comment: The tutorial link has been removed. It seems coredata changed a lot since then.